# Subtracting values from a row based off other columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

Sorry about the vague title it's hard to explain. It's easier to display.

I'm trying subtract values in the same row but based off strings in other columns. Here is an input df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

k = 5
N = 8

d = ({'Time' : np.random.randint(k, k + 100 , size=N),
    'Events' : ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'],
    'Number1' : ['xx','xx',1,'xx','xx','xx',2,'xx'],
    'Number2' : ['xx',1,'xx',1,'xx',2,'xx',2]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
  Events Number1 Number2  Time
0    ABC      xx      xx    14
1    DEF      xx       1    34
2    GHI       1      xx    78
3    JKL      xx       1    49
4    ABC      xx      xx    49
5    DEF      xx       2    24
6    GHI       2      xx    19
7    JKL      xx       2    67
```

I want to export values based on the difference in `Time`. The first time difference column will be `ABC - DEF` and the second column will be `GHI - JKL`.

I need to repeat this process a number of times. The example above displays a loop of 2 times. I can use the integers for columns `Number1` and `Number2` but they aren't in order.

I tried to combine and ffill these columns to display an order. And then use this column as a reference.

```
for col in ['Number2']:
    df[col] = df[col].ffill()
```

But this creates 5 identical integers when I need 4.

I then manually subtracted the appropriate values via row slicing but it becomes very inefficient when I have to do this numerous times.

Is it possible to create a loop subtracting the intended rows?

For the above example the output would be:

```
   Diff_1  Diff_2
0     -20      29
1      25     -48
```

Comment: Just completed this.

Comment: If an event is ABC will the next event always be DEF?

Comment: yep. Always in that order. So ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL. Then repeat that order. The amount of times this happens vary though. the example above displays this process twice. My datasets could be anywhere from 5-12 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

k = 5
N = 8

d = ({'Time' : np.random.randint(k, k + 100 , size=N),
    'Events' : ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'],
    'Number1' : ['xx','xx',1,'xx','xx','xx',2,'xx'],
    'Number2' : ['xx',1,'xx',1,'xx',2,'xx',2]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Events Number1 Number2  Time
0    ABC      xx      xx     8
1    DEF      xx       1    54
2    GHI       1      xx    52
3    JKL      xx       1    101
4    ABC      xx      xx    56
5    DEF      xx       2    34
6    GHI       2      xx    81
7    JKL      xx       2    23
```

This would have the new col in `df`. We only care about the rows for `ABC` and `GHI`

```
df['diff'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'].shift(-1)
diff = pd.DataFrame({
    'diff1' : list(df.loc[df['Events'] == 'ABC', 'diff']),
    'diff2' : list(df.loc[df['Events'] == 'GHI', 'diff'])
})
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
   diff1  diff2
0  -46.0  -49.0
1   22.0   58.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use shift to easily find the difference for a `df` that is ordered like that. But with this there are a lot of differences you don't care about. You want the 0th, 4th, 8th.... difference for the first difference and the 2nd, 6th, 10th... difference for the second difference. This is easy to accomplish with `.iloc`

```
import pandas as pd
diff = (df.Time-df.Time.shift(-1))

pd.DataFrame({'Diff_1': diff.iloc[::4].values,
              'Diff_2': diff.iloc[2::4].values})
#   Diff_1  Diff_2
#0   -20.0    29.0
#1    25.0   -48.0
```